# Earth engine: first() function on featureCollection does not extract a Feature?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I am trying to extract an element from a *featureCollection*, and apply the `area()` function to it. The output from *.first() looks exactly like a Feature, but yet, when I apply `area()`, I get:

> fromListFirst.area is not a function

I actually need to re-assign it the `ee.Feature` function to work. Likewise, if I were to extract the geometry from the feature, I will obtain something that looks much like a standard polygon, yet `area()` will refuse to work?

Question: what is happening exactly? Why does my object really look like a Feature, yet the area function does not work on it? It looks like a magic attribute is disappearing at some point?

```
var R1 = ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(30.01, 59.80, 30.59, 60.15),     
 {name: 'Voronoi'});

// Create a FeatureCollection with R1
var fromList = ee.FeatureCollection([R1,R1]);

// Extract first element with first():
var fromListFirst = fromList.first();

// reassign it the feature class:
var fromListFirstFeat = ee.Feature(fromListFirst);

// the original feature, the one obtained with first, 
//and the one with first then feaure appear to be exactly the same:
print('R1', R1)
print('fromListFirst', fromListFirst)
print('fromListFirstFeat', fromListFirstFeat)


// But last one won't work
var areaR1 = R1.area();
var areaFirstFeat = fromListFirstFeat.area();
var areaFirst = fromListFirst.area();

//extract geometry:
var aa = fromListFirstFeat.getInfo().geometry;
var areaAA = aa.area();
```

Comment: Here is the explanation you may find useful: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorial_gfw_04#calculating-the-area-of-sad-polygons

Comment: To paraphrase Tyler's answer, change  the offending lines to
var areaFirst = ee.Feature(fromListFirst).area()
var aa = fromListFirstFeat.geometry();
var areaAA = aa.area();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Earth Engine has the concept of collections (ee.Collection) that can contain elements (ee.Element) of various data types. The first() method returns the first element in the collection.

The ee.FeatureCollection and ee.ImageCollection classes inherit the base class methods, such as first(), from the parent ee.Collection class. However, because the first() method can return elements of arbitrary data types, it is not clear what data type will be returned for either ee.FeatureCollection.first() or ee.ImageCollection.first(), unless you explicitly cast the result to a particular data type. So

```
myCollection.first()
```

results in an object of an unknown data type, while using an explicit cast

```
ee.Feature(myCollection.first())
```

results in a feature.

Print() can take many object types as inputs, and can generally determine the correct type, so you don't need to make an explicit cast. Magic.